# I am trying to insert value directly to double pointer matrix as follows

Tags: c

```
int **matrix = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
int vertices = 4;
matrix = malloc(vertices * sizeof (int *));
```

so when I print the matrix, it is displaying garbage values.

Comment: So you've posted a couple declarations and a call to `malloc`, and you're saying you have trouble with some hidden code that's supposed to print something.  What sort of answer are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1**

First of all,

```
int **matrix = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
```

is syntactically incorrect. You can use:

```
int matrix[][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
```

**Point 2**

Second, if you use:

```
int **matrix = NULL; // Using a valid initializer
int vertices = 4;
matrix = malloc(vertices * sizeof (int *));
```

The elements of `matrix` remain uninitialized. Trying to access `matrix[0][0]` will result in undefined behavior. You'll have to allocate memory for each element of `matrix` before you can use it as a 2D array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i )
{
   matrix[i] = malloc(vertices*sizeof(int));
   for (int j = 0; j < vertices; ++j )
   {
      matrix[i][j] = 0; // Now you can assign values
   }
}
```

Also, make sure to check that `malloc` returned a valid pointer before proceeding to use it.

```
int **matrix = NULL; // Using a valid initializer
int vertices = 4;
matrix = malloc(vertices * sizeof (int *));
if ( matrix == NULL )
{
   // Deal with the problem.
}

for (int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i )
{
   matrix[i] = malloc(vertices*sizeof(int));
   if ( matrix[i] == NULL )
   {
      // Deal with the problem.
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < vertices; ++j )
   {
      matrix[i][j] = 0; // Now you can assign values
   }
}
```

**Point 3**

Third, if you use:

```
int matrix[][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
```

you cannot use:

```
matrix = malloc(vertices * sizeof (int *));
```

`matrix` an object of an array type. You cannot assign the return value of `malloc`, a pointe, to `matrix`.

Comment: And don't forget to check that the memory allocation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your matrix, then allocated memory it? You must first allocate memory, then fill data inside.

The reason you are seeing garbage numbers, you actually randomly got a memory space and its full of some data.